# How to make an pane stay over line connecting draggablenode in javafx

Tags: javafx, line, pane, drag

I am designing a UI of a graph structure with draggable nodes. In the graph I have a component called relation(it is a pane) which shows the link between two nodes.
I want relation to stay and move along with line at mid of line.

**Current UI design is as shown below**
[image]

**And the expected one is like:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the position of the node when the line's end coordinates are modified. To avoid triggering the calculation multiple times per layout pass, I recommend doing this from the `layoutChildren` method of the parent, but you could also do this from a listener to the `startX`, `endY`, ... properties. This will lead to some unnecessary computations though.

As for calcualting the position of the node: The center of the node needs to align with the midpoint of the line, so you need to solve the following equation for `markTopLeft`:

```
markTopLeft + (markWidth, markHeight) / 2 = (lineStart + lineEnd) / 2

markTopLeft = (lineStart + lineEnd - (markWidth, markHeight)) / 2
```

### Example

#### Pane allowing for custom layout calculations

```
public class PostProcessPane extends Pane {

    private final Set<Node> modifiedChildren = new HashSet<>();
    private final Set<Node> modifiedChildrenUnmodifiable = Collections.unmodifiableSet(modifiedChildren);
    private final List<Consumer<Set<Node>>> postProcessors = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Consumer<Set<Node>>> getPostProcessors() {
        return postProcessors;
    }

    private final ChangeListener listener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> modifiedChildren.add((Node) ((ReadOnlyProperty) o).getBean());

    private void initListener() {
        getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Node> c) -> {
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    for (Node n : c.getRemoved()) {
                        n.boundsInParentProperty().removeListener(listener);
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    for (Node n : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        n.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(listener);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public PostProcessPane() {
        initListener();
    }

    public PostProcessPane(Node... children) {
        super(children);
        initListener();

        for (Node n : children) {
            n.boundsInParentProperty().addListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();

        if (!modifiedChildren.isEmpty()) {
            for (Consumer<Set<Node>> processor : postProcessors) {
                processor.accept(modifiedChildrenUnmodifiable);
            }
            modifiedChildren.clear();
        }

    }

}
```

#### Usage

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(200, 50, Color.BLUE);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(200, 50, Color.RED);
    Rectangle mark = new Rectangle(200, 50, Color.YELLOW);
    Line line = new Line();

    r1.setX(20);
    r2.setX(380);
    r2.setY(450);

    PostProcessPane root = new PostProcessPane(line, r1, r2, mark);
    root.getPostProcessors().add(changedNodes -> {
        if (changedNodes.contains(r1) || changedNodes.contains(r2) || changedNodes.contains(mark)) {
            Bounds bounds1 = r1.getBoundsInParent();
            Bounds bounds2 = r2.getBoundsInParent();

            // refresh line ends
            line.setStartX(bounds1.getMinX() + bounds1.getWidth() / 2);
            line.setStartY(bounds1.getMaxY());
            line.setEndX(bounds2.getMinX() + bounds2.getWidth() / 2);
            line.setEndY(bounds2.getMinY());

            // recalculate mark position
            mark.setX((line.getStartX() + line.getEndX() - mark.getWidth()) / 2);
            mark.setY((line.getStartY() + line.getEndY() - mark.getHeight()) / 2);
        }
    });

    // add some movement for the nodes
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                    new KeyValue(r1.xProperty(), r1.getX()),
                    new KeyValue(r1.yProperty(), r1.getY()),
                    new KeyValue(r2.xProperty(), r2.getX())),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1),
                    new KeyValue(r2.xProperty(), r1.getX())),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),
                    new KeyValue(r1.xProperty(), r2.getX()),
                    new KeyValue(r1.yProperty(), r2.getY() / 2))
    );
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The code consists of bind property. so how can I do the same here too ??attribute.layoutXProperty()
   .bind((Bindings.add((node_link.endXProperty()), node_link.startXProperty()).divide(2)));
  attribute.layoutYProperty()
    .bind(Bindings.add((node_link.endYProperty()), node_link.startYProperty()).divide(2));

Comment: Also, I would like to rotate the arrow shown, in the direction in which the line linked with draggable node moves. Now the rotate property is enabled but angle is not correct.   arrowright.rotateProperty().bind(Bindings.add(node_link.endXProperty(), node_link.endYProperty()).multiply(1));
This is the code used.